# Распознавание лиц в реальном времени

Tags: android

Нужна библиотека для распознавания лиц в реальном времени, либо библиотека, которое позволит сравнивать фотографии. Нужно, чтобы при наведении на фотографию человека, этот человек как-то идентифицировался или сравнивался с теми же фотографиями, которые будут хранится в БД неважно как. Пробовал OpenCV, но как-то не зашло. 
Приложение должно быть офлайновым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно определять и сравнивать набор биометрических / антропометрических данных лица. С помощью [OpenBR](http://openbiometrics.org/) + несложной СУБД можно решить.

Еще есть интересные вещи - [Visage SDK](http://visagetechnologies.com/products-and-services/visagesdk/) и [DLIB](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/released-dlib-facelandmark-detector.408958/)

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на Google Cloud Vision: https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Демо с последнего Google I/O: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpPyhsC4q9M